# Creating a SoP Energy Wall in a straight line

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spheres-of-power, wall

Using the [Spheres of Power rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/), the destruction sphere has a talent called Energy Wall

> You may spend a spell point to shape your destructive blast into either a wall up to 20 ft. per caster level or a hemisphere with a radius up to 5 ft. per 2 caster levels (minimum: 5 ft). This wall extends up to 20 ft. high and lasts for 1 round per caster level. The wall does not block line of effect, line of sight, projectiles, or thrown objects.
>
> Creatures passing through your wall suffer your destructive blast’s damage and effects as normal. Creatures standing in the wall’s space when it is created are allowed a Reflex save to avoid damage.

I have the following questions:

- Does the wall have to be created in a straight line (if not using the hemisphere version)?
- If the wall is a straight line, say down a 5 foot wide corridor, would someone traveling down the corridor take damage each square of movement?

Answer (score 1):

### The wall needs to be a straight line.

Another SoP talent, Wall of Darkness, specifies that it may be "..up to [3 plus CL] 10-ft cubes... arranged contiguously, but otherwise may assume any shape." Energy Wall has no such language, so one would think it is a more traditional wall.

### You most likely deal your damage only once.

Once again, I'm forced to point to a lack of rules. Energy Wall has a specific association with Air Blast "If using Energy Wall, each square of wall is considered the center of effect for those who enter that section."

Because other effects have no such language, it would seem that's an exception and not the norm. Additionally,

> Creatures passing through your wall...

seems like it would only happens once per movement. This is supported by a balance concern of dealing full spell damage multiple times in a reactive stance. If the damage was reduced by turning it into a wall, that would be different.